# How to wrap ETH into WETH via ethers.js or web3.js?

Tags: ether, ethers.js, uniswap, uniswapv3, wrapped-tokens

what  function in a smart contract is responsible for this?

In the documentation of Uniswap I've found only one reference to what I might be looking -- https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/universal-router/technical-reference#wrap_eth

However, how to used and implement this in ethers or web3.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the `deposit` method:

https://etherscan.io/token/0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2#writeContract#F5

After calling `deposit` method, the caller will received `WETH` equal to the `ETH` amount paid to the contract.

As usual, double-check and triple-check the contract is actually authentic.

How to interact with contract in ethers.js or web3.js should already be covered in their documentation.

Comment: `After calling deposit method, the caller will received WETH equal to the ETH amount paid to the contract.` --> where have you gotten this information from? Where is it written?

Comment: You can go to https://info.uniswap.org/ and check on ETH token, which is actually WETH. In that page, there is a link to etherscan.io. The token was not created by Ethereum Foundation so there's no documentation on their site, so it is like de-facto standard that people use the specified contract as WETH.

Comment: Alright. But why does it not work on Goerli? Although it exists there

Comment: There is a [WETH contract](https://goerli.etherscan.io/token/0xb4fbf271143f4fbf7b91a5ded31805e42b2208d6#writeContract) on Goerli at a different address (I just googled it). Noted that on Testnet you might use whichever equivalent WETH contract you want for testing, as long as it works the same as the WETH contract on mainnet.